# Python Selenium Webdriver: Repeating the same information in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve text from the website (https://www.doc.govt.nz/parks-and-recreation/places-to-go/otago/places/dunedin-area/?tab-id=50578). I am trying to extract information present on the website. Here is my code that is retrieving the text:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
driver.get('https://www.doc.govt.nz/parks-and-recreation/places-to-go/otago/places/dunedin-area/?tab-id=50578')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="profile-detail"]'):

    desc = element.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="profile-detail-body"]').text
    info = element.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="profile-info"]').text

    print(desc)
    print(info)
```

The problem is that it always repeats the first entry of the information present on the page (i.e. Allans Beach Track information). When I tried to retrieve the information using two separate loops, it works fine. Could you please guide me where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is to understand the structure of the elements and then
>   define your scripting strategy .
>
> I believe you are trying to access each list item present in the list
>   "class="profileRepeater" which has multiple entries of
>   "class="profile-info" and "profile-detail-body".

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
driver.get('https://www.doc.govt.nz/parks-and-recreation/places-to-go/otago/places/dunedin-area/?tab-id=50578')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

parentElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name('profileRepeater')

for listItemElement in parentElement.find_element_by_tag_name('li'):

    desc = listItemElement.find_element_by_class_name('profile-detail-body').text
    info = listItemElement.find_element_by_class_name('profile-info').text

    print(desc)
    print(info)
```

> this should print all of the different values in search results list
>   items

Answer (score 0):

When using `xpath` to locate an element from another element you need to specify current context `.` before the second path

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="profile-detail"]'):
    desc = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="profile-detail-body"]').text
    info = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="profile-info"]').text
```

You can use `class_name` instead without any conditions

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('profile-detail'):
    desc = element.find_element_by_class_name('profile-detail-body').text
    info = element.find_element_by_class_name('profile-info').text
```